# How to find the AWS Amplify appId?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, app-id

I have a working AWS Amplify application which I deployed manually. To specify this application using the CLI, [I need the so-called `appId`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/APIReference/API_App.html). But where can I find this? In the console, I can find the name and the `appArn` but not the `appId`.
[image: ScreenshotOfApp]

Comment: In your application directory, look in the /amplify/backend/amplify-meta.json file.  You should see "AmplifyAppId" in there

Comment: I haven't got such a folder. I just uploaded a zip with the build folder content in it.

Comment: OK if you go into the AMS Amplify screen then choose App settings and then General (menu left side of the screen), you should see the "App details" screen.  Look for the App ARN.  The last part of this string should be your app id.  So for example "dt2d2jf2cliyx" in this dummy App ARN : arn:aws:amplify:eu-central-1:9999999999:apps/dt2d2jt2cliyx

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have access to the AWS console and can see the `App ARN` field, you can find the `AppId`:

```
arn:aws:amplify:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx/APPID
```

It has this pattern: `d[a-z0-9]+`